# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity error

Tags: java, android

I'm having an (with some devices) error caused by NullPointerException error with this code :

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

it's forces the screen orientation to portrait, is it well coded? because the error reports comes from a few  android 4.4 devices.

---

UPDATES

---

As Mr. Gabe said, i guess line 35 is about here if imports line are hidden [+] :

```
 Thread t = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, main.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
   here ------>
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This code is from splash activity, it's goes to main activity after 3 sec, i think everything here looks fine to me, what's can cause an NPE here?

---

UPDATE

---

the error report from the google play is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{aladin888.dessin/aladin888.dessin.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:4453)
at aladin888.dessin.Splash.<init>(Splash.java:35)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
```

PS:How to make the lines numbers show up in eclipse?

Comment: Are you sure about the line?  Is there a possibility they have a different version which has different line numbers?  Because nothing here looks like it could cause a NPE.

Comment: Changing the orientation of the device causes some of the current activity's method to be executed (I don't remember which), and if you activity doesn't handle orientation changes properly, you could get in trouble. However, this line is not enough to help you. You need to post the entire activity code.

Comment: I added error report,can you check please what's wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its fine and should work easily
Here is what i am using and is working fine too
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Answer (score 0):

Although your codeline is fine, this error could have been cause due to invalid usage of 'this' key word.

Try using the xml alternative. Go to androidmanifest.xml and write
<
activity

android:name=".MyActivity"

android:label="@string/app_name"

android:screenOrientation="portrait" >